# Difference between 쓰다 and 적다

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

안녕하세요!

I am a bit curious about the difference between `쓰다` and `적다`. For example which one is a better translation for *"The woman writes a book"*:

1. 여자는 책을 **씁니다**;
2. 여자는 책을 **적습이다**;

??

Comment: 적습니다 is a correct expression

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Sorry for a superficial question, it was pretty easy to find an answer, but let me just share the knowledge here, as in wiki</sup>

### Definitions

#### 쓰다 - creatively writing

`쓰다` is used when you are writing something creative and meaningful. You act as an author.

Use cases: creating (writing) books, writing letters, writing texts of the songs, writing this article (check my last chapter of this paper :D ).

#### 적다 - making notes

`적다` is mostly about the simple process of writing symbols on paper/on the screen, to save something in a written form. So, it is mostly about the mechanical process of hand-movement.

Use cases: making notes, writing the shopping lists, saving the phone number in an old-style contact-book.

### Question about translation

So, the most suitable translation for the original sentence *"The woman writes a book"* depends on the woman and her book. If that sentence was about another one "Harry Potter and something" book from Joanne Rowling — it is definitely `쓰다`. But if the woman is my neighbor and she is filling a register-book of her daily purchases — `작다` would fit better.

### See also

- [wiseinit.com](https://wiseinit.com/%EC%93%B0%EB%8B%A4-%EC%A0%81%EB%8B%A4-korean-words-vs-words-20/) explanation
- [duolingo.com](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/24372669/%EC%A0%80%EB%8A%94-%EB%A9%94%EC%8B%9C%EC%A7%80%EB%A5%BC-%EC%A0%81%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4) discussion